# One NFS server to multiple clients

Tags: nfs

How do I set up an NFS server to multiple clients?
I have set up an NFS server but it does only share to one client.

Comment: WHat does `/etc/exports` contain? Have you added the other clients IPs or hostnames to it?

Answer (score 16):

In your /etc/exports file, you can either use a wildcard:

```
/path/to/share    *(rw,sync,etc)
```

Or you can use CIDR notation

```
/path/to/share    10.0.0.0/24(rw,sync)
```

Or you can put multiple IPs in line like so:

```
/path/to/share    10.0.0.5(rw) 10.0.0.6(ro)
```

Comment: +1 for adding CIDR blocks, just what I was looking for

Comment: +1 for multiple IPs in one line

Comment: Beware the pitfall of `10.0.0.5 (rw) 10.0.0.6(ro)` where you *think* you grant read/write to `.5` but you are - due to the *space* between ip and permission - reverting to default for `.5` and grating read/write to *all* hosts.

Answer (score 1):

This website quite clearly explains how to setup NFS Server and Clients.  It helped me setup my first lot.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-14-04

Give it a shot and you'll find yourself never using samba nor CIFS ever again!

Comment: From ["Ask Ubuntu Help"](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer): Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.